# SQL 'LIKE' operator in Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, sql-like, hibernate-criteria

I want to implement some universal filter with Hibernate `Criteria`. It should work like `LIKE` operator from SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.ANYCOLOUMNHERE LIKE '%'||anyvaluehere||'%'
```

I have `Map<String, String>` where *key* is a column name, and *value* is its value.

I tried something like this:

```
for (Entry<String, String> filter : filters.entrySet()) {
    crit.add(Restrictions.ilike(filter.getKey(), filter.getValue(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
}
```

But when field type is not *String*, it causes  `java.lang.ClassCastException`:

```
[com.nsn.util.LoggerUtilerror] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error while getting alarms: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongTypeDescriptor.unwrap(LongTypeDescriptor.java:36) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:57) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:92) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:305) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1891) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1862) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2447) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2433) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2263) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2258) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:122) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1535) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:396) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at com.nsn.entities_proccess.AlarmDAOImpl.getAlarms(AlarmDAOImpl.java:93) [classes:]
    at com.nsn.boundary_process.LazyAlarmDataModel.load(LazyAlarmDataModel.java:50) [classes:]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:677) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:92) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:518) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1411) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:297) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:981) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:391) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: What is the exception message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend using a `Query object` instead of the `Criteria object`, in this case.

I can't remember if Criteria passes things it doesn't understand straight through to the database like a Query object will do. Basically what this would mean is that if you used a function that was database specific that the Hibernate parser didn't understand, it would pass it "as is" to the database.

Example:

```
Query queryObject = session.createQuery("from ClassName where VARIABLENAME like '%'||anyvaluehere||'%' order by VARIABLENAME");
List<YourClass> resultList= queryObject.list();
```

For more see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: Can you show small example please. Especially how to implement sorting

Answer (score 29):

You can use [`like()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#ilike-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode-) restriction criteria like this:

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Pojo.class);
query.add(Restrictions.like("anycolumn", "anyvalue", MatchMode.START));
```

It will give you a list of strings that start with "*anyvalue*".

Answer (score 12):

You can use DetachedCriteria also when the hibernate session is not present.

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Pojo.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("column", value, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

It will match the **value** anywhere in the **column** string.
You can use different types of modes.

Reference page: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/MatchMode.html

**DetachedCriteria:**
 - Detached criteria is very good alternate when the hibernate session is not present.

Using a DetachedCriteria is exactly the same as a Criteria except you can do the initial creation and setup of your query without having access to the session. When it comes time to run your query, you must convert it to an executable query with `getExecutableCriteria(session)`.

This is useful if you are building complicated queries, possibly through a multi-step process, because you don't need access to the Session everywhere. You only need the Session at the final step when you run the query.

Under the hood, DetachedCriteria uses a CriteriaImpl which is the same class you get if you call `session.createCriteria()`.

Comment: MatchMode.ANYWHERE will match the value anywhere in the column string... but what does the DetachedCriteria do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the enum MatchMode to help you with it:

```
Criterion c1 = Restrictions.like("AttributeName", "AttributeValue", MatchMode.END);
```

Don't use any special character, like * 
Referencce [Read This Like](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/MatchMode.html)

Answer (score -1):

> when field type is not String, it couse java.lang.ClassCastException

thats because it only works with string/varchar fields/columns.

Comment: So is there a way to implement sql 'like' behavior with criteria?

Comment: yeah loads of different ways, but how would you "like" a boolean for example ? Or an Integer ? Or Foo ?

Comment: Like it working in sql. Here you can select anything dont care about column type.

Comment: @Divers Its oracle specific then, and certainly not applicable to hibernate