# Hibernate "Like" expressions on two sides Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I'd like to use criteria and create something like this but with hibernate criterias:

```
WHERE concat(X, Y) like '%Some Value%'
```

I don't want to do it using query concatenation, but using Restrictions because I am making a dynamic library that gets the left and right side of the like operator? Am I clear? Please if not ask me to give more clarification.

Thank you!

Comment: [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328403/implement-sql-like-in-criteria-hibernate) recommends not using a Criteria object.

Comment: .add( Restrictions.like("name", "%"+yourValue+"%") ) is not enough?

Comment: @bryce what I want is that the "name" is a concatenation, not a column property.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you're right, thank you, but unfortunately at the current time I can't change. Query would make it much easier for me in many other aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it may works.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Table.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.ilike("param1 || param2", "%" + dniWithLetter + "%"));
```

If the above code not working, please go through the following link.
[Can we concatenate two properties in Hibernate HQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910428/can-we-concatenate-two-properties-in-hibernate-hql-query/17910472#17910472)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution for your problem is the following

```
...
Object[] params = {objX, objY, someValue};
Type[] typeOfParams = {Hibernate.STRING, Hibernate.STRING, Hibernate.STRING};
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Table.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("concat(?, ?) like '%?%'", params, typeOfParams));
...
```

When you use `Restrictions.sqlRestriction`, you can build a complex query with multiple parameters, you just have to set the parameters and type of each parameter, this is done with `params` array and `typeOfparams` array.

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.