# JPA criteria like with OneToOne join

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteria

I need to search data which contain string parameter

I have 2 entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "referentiel_digital")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class ReferentielDigital implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "libelle_commercial", length = 200, nullable = false)
    private String libelleCommercial;

    @Size(max = 1000)
    @Column(name = "description_courte", length = 1000)
    private String descriptionCourte;

    @Size(max = 1000)
    @Column(name = "description_longue", length = 1000)
    private String descriptionLongue;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private Referentiel reference;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "referentiel")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Referentiel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private UUID uuid;

    ....

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "reference")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("referentiels")
    private ReferentielDigital digital;
```

I develop a search API, which uses JPA Criteria. It works very well with different fields, and join (ManyToOne), but in this case, I need to find Referentiel, which contains string in referentielDigital.descriptionLongue in example.

I try this:

```
        Join<Referentiel, ReferentielDigital> digital = root.join("digital");
        Expression<String> exp1 = digital.get("libelleCommercial");


        Predicate p1 = exp1.in("%" + criteria.getLibelle() + "%");

        Expression<String> exp2 = digital.get("descriptionCourte");
        Predicate p2 = exp1.in("%" + criteria.getLibelle() + "%");

        Expression<String> exp3 = digital.get("descriptionLongue");
        Predicate p3 = exp1.in("%" + criteria.getLibelle() + "%");

        predicates.add(cb.or(p1, p2, p3));
```

It does not work because request contains "in", and I want to have "like" for obtain good result.

With Extension object, I have not "like" method.

How can I do like request with this join please?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#like-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-java.lang.String-

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328403/sql-like-operator-in-hibernate-criteria-api) is a similar question.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

i found solution with JB Nizet Help :

```
        Join<Referentiel, ReferentielDigital> digital = root.join("digital");
        Expression<String> exp1 = digital.get("libelleCommercial");

        Predicate p1 = cb.like(exp1, "%" + criteria.getLibelle() + "%");

        Expression<String> exp2 = digital.get("descriptionCourte");
        Predicate p2 = cb.like(exp2, "%" + criteria.getLibelle() + "%");

        Expression<String> exp3 = digital.get("descriptionLongue");
        Predicate p3 = cb.like(exp3, "%" + criteria.getLibelle() + "%");

        predicates.add(cb.or(p1, p2, p3));
```